# run function on frame when window finish load

Tags: javascript, html

I want to run function click on spesific id inside a frame, so i make two html file and i write the script like this

the main html is this `index.html`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <script type="text/javascript">
       function autoClick(){
    document.getElementById('framing').contentWindow.document.getElementById('trig').click();
        }
       </script>
     </head>
     <body onload="autoClick();">
            <iframe name="framing" id="framing" src="testing.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="1200px" width="100%"></iframe>
     </body>
    </html>
```

and another one is the `testing.html`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script>
       window.onbeforeunload = function(){
       return false; // This will stop the redirecting.
      }
      </script>
     </head>
    <body>
    <div>
      <a id="trig" href='http://www.redirect.com/' target='iName'>Home</a>
    </div>
        <iframe src="about:blank" name="iName" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="1200px" width="100%"></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

so when `index.html` finish load the page, i want the function to click on the  `<a id=trig" href='http://www.redirect.com/' target='iName'>Home</a>`
 on `testing.html` that inside frame `framing`
and when it clicked, the `trig` will load a site `http://www.redirect.com` that will be contained inside `iName` frame, but the site `http://www.redirect.com` have a script that will redirect the TLD to the their site, so i put the script for preventing the page to break out the iframe `      
       window.onbeforeunload = function(){
       return false; // This will stop the redirecting.
      }

this two html file is hosted on same domain. but when i try to run it, the function click is not triggered, anyone can help me?

Thank you, and sorry for the bad english, it is not my native language

Comment: so i need to add settimeout to the autoclick in the onload?

Comment: the iframe already load, but it doesn't run the click script

Comment: I'm a derp ... see the error here `<a id=trig"` ... fix that, and all will be well - though

Comment: i see, i miss that one too..i working well now, but i just read that function .click() only works on IE, is there any script for auto click that run well on chrome and firefox? thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: `but i just read that function .click() only works on IE` - erm, no, it works in firefox as well, it's a pretty standard function

Comment: ah, the script run on firefox as well, but it doesnt trigger the script to prevent the source page to break out the frame and still redirect TLD to the source page, actually all this script is trying to find another way to allow sandboxed iframe to able run flash on the source page.